# SQL Server : Group By Group Title and Group Sum and Total Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
   Table2Id int,
   Stock int,
   Price money
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price) 
VALUES ('2','55','2');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('2','46','3');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('2','47','6');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('2','45','4');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('3','58','5');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('3','51','1');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('4','24','33');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('4','53','72');

INSERT INTO Table1 (Table2Id, Stock, Price)
VALUES ('4','21','91');


CREATE TABLE Table2
(
   Id      int,
   Field1 varchar(5),
   Field2 varchar(5),
   Field3 varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES ('2','A','A1','A2');

INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES ('3','B','B1','B2');

INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES ('4','C','C1','C2');


SELECT 
   t1.Table2Id, t1.Price, t1.Stock,
   t2.Field1, t2.Field2, t2.Field3 
FROM 
   Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
   Table2 t2 ON t1.Table2Id = t2.Id
GROUP BY 
   t1.Table2Id, t1.Price, t1.Stock, t2.Field1, t2.Field2, t2.Field3
```

This query result is

```
Table2Id    Price           Stock       Field1      Field2      Field3 
2           2,00            55          A           A1          A2
2           3,00            46          A           A1          A2
2           4,00            45          A           A1          A2
2           6,00            47          A           A1          A2
3           1,00            51          B           B1          B2
3           5,00            58          B           B1          B2
4           33,00           24          C           C1          C2
4           72,00           53          C           C1          C2
4           91,00           21          C           C1          C2
```

But I want to this result.

```
        Table2Id    Price    Stock   Field1   Field2   Field3    GroupTotal   Total
G Header -> 2           NULL     NULL    A        A1       A2        NULL         NULL
            NULL        2,00     55      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
            NULL        3,00     46      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
            NULL        4,00     45      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
            NULL        6,00     47      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
G Footer -> NULL        NULL     NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL      15,00        NULL
G Header -> 3           NULL     NULL    B        B1       B2        NULL         NULL
            NULL        1,00     51      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
            NULL        5,00     58      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
G Footer -> NULL        NULL     NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL      6,00         NULL      
G Header -> 4           NULL     NULL    C        C1       C2        NULL         NULL
            NULL        33,00    24      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
            NULL        72,00    53      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
            NULL        91,00    21      NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
G Footer -> NULL        NULL     NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL      196,00       NULL
Total F. -> NULL        NULL     NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL      NULL         217,00
```

How can I get this result.

it's a very difficult problem for me. Please help me.

Comment: What are you using to display this report?  Totals like this are often best handled at that level.

Comment: Look into using windowed sets which is a function of the `over partition by` syntax.  [Docs & Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)  I don't think you can get the G header and footer with the null values without using control break logic in a report easily.  But the totals should be easily doable using the `OVER`syntax in the link.  OR [group by grouping sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 4 Seperate Sub queries for the different kinds of row

One for the data rows
One for the group headers
One for the group footers
One for the report footer

In each one include a Rowtype column so they should each return columns 
RowType, Table2Id,Price,Stock, Field1, Field2, Field3, GroupTotal,Total

and you can then use UNION ALL clauses to put all the rows together and an Order by clause to get them in the order you want,

You can use CASE statements in the column list of the the select statement to return NULLs when you want to

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='GH' THEN d.Table2Id ELSE NULL END as Table2Id,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='D' THEN d.Price ELSE NULL END as Price,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='D' THEN d.Stock ELSE NULL END as Stock,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='GH' THEN d.Field1 ELSE NULL END as Field1,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='GH' THEN d.Field2 ELSE NULL END as Field2,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='GH' THEN d.Field3 ELSE NULL END as Field3,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='GF' THEN d.Price ELSE NULL END as GroupTotal,
CASE WHEN d.RowType ='RF' THEN d.Price ELSE NULL END as Total
FROM 
(
SELECT 
'D' as RowType,
t1.Table2Id, t1.Price, t1.Stock,t2.Field1,t2.Field2,t2.Field3 FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Table2Id=t2.Id
union all
SELECT 
'GH' as RowType,
 Table2Id,  0 as Price, 0 as Stock,t2.Field1,t2.Field2,t2.Field3 FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Table2Id=t2.Id
GROUP BY Table2Id,t2.Field1,t2.Field2,t2.Field3 
union all
SELECT 
'GF' as RowType,
 Table2Id, SUM(PRice) as Price, 0 as Stock,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Table2Id=t2.Id
GROUP BY Table2Id
union all
SELECT 
'RF' as RowType,
0 as Table2Id, SUM(PRice) as Price, 0 as Stock,null as Field1,null as Field2,null as Field3 FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Table2Id=t2.Id
) d
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN d.RowType = 'RF' then 1 ELSE 0 END,
 d.Table2Id,
CASE WHEN d.RowType = 'GH' then 0 
WHEN d.RowType = 'D' then 1
WHEN d.RowType = 'GF' then 2
ELSE 4 END
```

Comment: thanks Tom but I ordered by inserting row time. Is it possible to nevertheless?

Comment: You're going to order the results as follows
Report Totals to the end
Field1, Field2, Field3
Group Headers first
Group Footers last
And then what ever sorting you want for the data rows

When I've finished this install I'll do some code that should make it easier

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general gist of group by grouping sets...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/503fd/16/0

I used a Common table expression so I didn't have to play around with the sum of price all over the place.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT t1.Table2Id, SUM(t1.Price) PRICE, t1.Stock,t2.Field1,t2.Field2,t2.Field3 
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
 ON t1.Table2Id=t2.Id
GROUP BY grouping sets 
((t1.Table2Id, t1.Price, t1.Stock,t2.Field1,t2.Field2,t2.Field3), 
 (t1.Table2Id),
 ()))
SELECT table2ID
, case when stock is null then null else price  end as Price
, Stock
, Field1
, Field2
, Field3
, Case when stock is null and table2ID is not null then price else null end as GroupTotal
, case when table2ID is null then Price else null end as Total
FROM CTE;
```

Again this doesn't handle the header/footer rows but it does handle the math and placement of the values in the correct columns.

If this were combined with a Pivot... you might be able to achieve the header breaks; but I'm struggling seeing it.

Comment: I have to solve this problem in a way. Thank you for your help xQbert.